# python print sentences with common word or frequency words?

Tags: python, dataset, extract, frequency, sentence

i have a data set and i want print all sentences with most frequency word 
like:

example imagine i have this:

[image]
this is the frequency of my dataset

[image]

and this is my original dataset

i want print all sentences contain (i) and then delete those extract sentences from dataset

then start with (you) and print all the sentences that contain (you) and then delete (you)

but i want set the range between them example start from (frequency 600 to 100) not all of them 
how to do it

any idea how to do it ? my dataset is .txt

i tried this one :

Comment: The description is not clear enough. You want to print the count of the common words (I, You, We) or you want to print the sentences where they appear? In either case - what do you mean by common words - do you have a list ? or do you want to consider the top 5 or 10 most recurring words?....Please describe the problem statement more clearly...

Comment: Also post what you've already tried, it makes easier to help

Comment: example i want print all sentences which (i) appeared and then delete those sentences from original dataset

Comment: sorry i could not find the suitable answer and i tried multiple way but i failed

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, you want to do a for i in range() for some values from a txt file. I would suggest reading from the file into a dictionary {} so you can use key value pairs to determine when to stop checking.

Comment: thanks for replying i already have the dictionary but i can not do the next step which i explained in the top

Comment: can you post or comment your code so I can understand where you are up to.